# Migrating from Drupal to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, svn, drupal, drupal-7, migration

We are planning to move to new CMS from Drupal to WordPress. While exploring, I came across this [site](http://webhostingmedia.net/migrate-drupal-to-wordpress/) to move the contents if it is stored in git.

But our code base is in SVN, Could anyone suggest what are the best ways I can migrate it from Drupal to Wordpress when codebase is hosted in SVN.It would be good if provided solution does not include purchasing new plugins for migration.

Thanks for help !!!

Comment: When i read the link, plugin is on github you need to download it and install it as any wp plugin ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the contents like articles, pages, categories and images from Drupal to wordpress but not the template so you need to work on template/theme first for wordpress.

Using the following plugin you can directly import contents from you drupal database:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/fg-drupal-to-wp/screenshots/

I have added the plugin link of screenshots as you can see you just need to provide database details and plugin will do the rest.

It is not an easy process to take backup of everything properly before doing the migration.

Comment: In the installation of plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/fg-drupal-to-wp/installation/ ... i am facing this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/q/41189334/1877909